# How to retrieve the value of a cookie by its name right from URL Bar

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've changed the value of a cookie on the site by typing `javascript:document.cookie="CName=cValue"` in the URL Bar.

What script can I write to retrieve the value of cookie "CName" using a similar script right from the URL bar

Answer (score 0):

Check it out.

```
javascript:function getCookie(name) {var value = '; ' + document.cookie;var parts = value.split('; ' + name + '=');if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();}alert(getCookie('CName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For something quick and dirty, that you type each time to *view* a cookie:

`document.cookie.match(/\b__hstc=[^;]+/)`

where `__hstc` is the name of the cookie you want.

you might also want to wrap *unescape* around it, and don't forget `javascript:` url conventions.

It works well even in devtools as well, which for some reason still has no cookie interface.

this is not a production-ready cookie method, but it gets the job done quickly in 99% of cases.